# findOne not returning correct result( Mongo DB and nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have stored a document in collection and when i am trying to retrieve it via findOne, it is returning me wrong result:
My Mongoose model is like:

```
var db = require('../db');
var mongoose = db.mongoose_var;
var companySchema = mongoose.Schema({
companyName:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company',companySchema);
```

Which then i am using in my server.js as :

```
var CompanySchema = require('./schemas/companySchema');
```

and when I am trying to find already inserted record as following:

```
CompanySchema.findOne({'Company.companyName':jsonObj.companyName},function(err,companyName){
 console.log('companyName foudn:'+companyName);
 if(companyName !== null){
    res.status(404).json({status:'Name already in the DB'});
    return;
    }else{...
```

Its unable to find this record, but its returning probably the first record.
Folloing record is present in thedb:
[image]

When I am trying to add another company and using this findOne to check if this name already exists, findOne returns this record only. My log snippets

[image]

whereas mongo shell returns proper result only.

[image]

In mongo shell, I am using " " around field and values, not in findOne Api.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe unrelated but just in case anyone ends up here as did I... had a similar problem where `findOne` was returning a "record" when it shouldn't be. However, I eventually realised it was returning the Promise. Doh I always make that mistake, remember to `await`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the following :

```
CompanySchema.findOne({'companyName':jsonObj.companyName},function(err,companyDocument){
if(err) console.log(err);
console.log('company found:' + companyDocument);
if(companyDocument){
res.status(404).json({status:'Name already in the DB'});
return;
}else{...
```

The mistake in your code was that you were using **Company.companyName** instead of companyName. companyName is the name of the field in the Company collection.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'll be able to test by evening , will update the thread then **but** I remember trying every possible combination and result was the same. I will check again.
But even if I am putting the field in findOne(**<field>**,value) in wrong  way, it should not return any successful result. **I am expecting null object** in that case.

Comment: Exactly, the query will return null. You're not putting the field in the wrong way. The field you're querying on(Company.companyName) doesn't exist. companyName is the field in the company collection. So findOne should return null with your query.

Comment: But the current query is not returning null.Check the second screenshot of terminal window in the main question. I am looking for "someCompanyName2" via findOne and it is returning "someComapanyName1"

Comment: Can you please type in the whole code so that I could understand what you're doing? I need to have a look at your findOne call on the CompanySchema.